# Target component nested in ng-content

Tags: angular

I am trying to target a component that is nested in `ng-content` and handle it like `ViewChild`. For example, `ComponentB` is placed inside `ng-content` of `ComponentA`.

What I am trying to do is similar to:

```js
@ViewChild('componentB') componentBViewChild: ComponentB;
```

so I can use the functionality of it like:

```js
this.componentBViewChild.functionFoo();
```

The problem is that I am not able to add a reference in order to target the nested component.

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@ContentChild` instead of `@ViewChild` for referencing projected content. `@ViewChild` only finds elements that are directly found within the `Component`'s HTML template.

For example, given a `ComponentA` with the following HTML:

```html
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Which is used as follows:

```html
<component-a>
  <component-b></component-b>
</component-a>
```

You can reference `ComponentB` from `ComponentA` as follows:

```js
@ContentChild(ComponentB) componentB: ComponentB;
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild).